# What is the value of the given limit?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prove Infinitesimal Limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89575/how-can-i-prove-infinitesimal-limit)

Let $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}=0$$
Then what is the value of  $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$$

Comment: I think that the above value depend on the derivation of $f$!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89575/how-can-i-prove-infinitesimal-limit).

Answer (score 4):

For every $\delta > 0$ there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $|f(2x) - f(x)| < \delta\, |x|$ if $x\neq 0$ and $|x| < \varepsilon$.  Then for all integers $k \geq 0$ $$ \begin{eqnarray}
|f(2x) - f(2^{-k}x)| &=& |f(2x) - f(x) + f(x) - f(2^{-1}x) + \dotsc + f(2^{1-k}x) - f(2^{-k}x)|\\ &<& \delta \,|x| + \delta\, 2^{-1}|x| + \dotsc + \delta \, 2^{-k}|x|\\ &<& 2\delta \, |x| \end{eqnarray}$$ and since $\lim_{k \to \infty}f(2^{-k}x) = 0$ this implies that $|f(2x)| \leq 2\delta \, |x|$ if $|x| < \varepsilon$.  Therefore $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=L$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(2x)}{x} =  2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(2x)}{2x} = 2\lim_{u\to0}\frac{f(u)}{u} = 2L.
$$
Then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(2x)}{x} - \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x} =\cdots 
$$
etc.

**Later note:** What is written above holds in cases in which $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists.  The question remains: If both $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0}(f(2x)-f(x))/x=0$ then does it follow that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists?

Comment: How do you know the limit exists? (-1) for that.

Comment: We do not know that $f$ is derivative!

Comment: @aliakbar You mean differentiable? If $f$ is continuous at $0$ then the existence of that limit is equivalent to differentiability of $f$ at $0$. Of course, we don't even know if $f$ is continuous at $0$ let alone differentiable

Comment: @Nameless : I started from the assumption that the limit exists, so what I wrote applies in all cases in which the limit exists.  I believe I can show there are some functions $f$ for which $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to0}(f(x)/x)$ does not exist.

Comment: @MichaelHardy If you can construct such an example and post it here I will upvote your answer. (you also want $\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}\to 0$)

Comment: @Michael Those examples are not hard to construct (e.g. $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational, $f(x) = 0$ otherwise) but the extra condition $[f(2x) - f(x)]/x \to 0$ doesn't work for those.

Comment: no.Be carefull!

Comment: I believe that $f$ should be derivative.