# Proving $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} =l$

Tags: real-analysis

let $f$ a continuos function on $\mathbb{R}$

such that:

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x} =l$

proof that $f$ is derivable at 0 and $f'(0)=l$

i have tried to use the definition but i couldn't extract $f(2x)$

please help me with this question

Comment: The title and the question  differ very much. What is the hypothesis and what is the conclusion?

Comment: See [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89575/if-fx-and-f2x-fx-x-have-limit-0-as-x-to-0-then-fx-x-to-0)

Comment: Notice that : 
$$\dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} = \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{f(x/2^n) - f(x/2^{n + 1})}{x/2^{n + 1}} \dfrac{1}{2^{n + 1}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $f$ being derivable at $0$ is
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.$$
You can split
$$\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}=2\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x}-\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.$$
Can you follow from here?

**Edit**: as requested, I'm developing the proof a bit more. Take limits in the expression above to get
$$l=\lim_{x\to 0}\left( 2\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x}-\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right).$$
Now, use the fact that the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits iff the summands' limits exist. So,
$$l=2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$
iff both of the summands' limits exist. But, since $f$ is continuous (particularly at $0$) it doen't matter in which way you take the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$. Therefore, these limits are equal if they exist:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}.$$
Then,
$$l=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$$
iff the limit in the RHS exists. Done.

Comment: You cannot conclude from this that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @Andrés Cárcel can you continue on your proof because i still don't get the idea

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: This answer is based on the assumption that the limit exists. You have not yet proven the limit exists. And proof f is derivable at 0(i.e. limit exists) is one part of the question.

Comment: True! OP, unaccept the answer so I can delete it.