# If $\lim\limits_{x\to0}f(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{x}=0$ how to rigorously prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I saw this problem on my problem book:

> IF $\lim\limits_{x\to0 }f(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0 }\frac{f(2x)- f(x)}{x} =0$  prove that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=0 $.

I tried to solve it but failed the only thing that I was able to prove its that if $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist in $\overline {\mathbb{R}}$it it either $0$ or $\pm \infty$ and that it east to show
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(2x)}{x}   + 2\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)}{2x}$$

i.e $L = 2L$

But I was not able to prove that the limit exist .

Comment: If $\lim_{x\to a} h_1(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} h_2(x)$ exists then $\lim_{x\to a} (h_1(x)\pm h_2(x))$ exists and it is equal to $\lim_{x\to a} h_1(x)\pm\lim_{x\to a} h_2(x)$ by properties of limits. Taking $h_1 = (f(x)-f(2x))/x$, $h_2 = f(2x)/2x$ and $a=0$, you should be done.

Comment: @Sam Why does $\lim h_2(x)$ exist?

Comment: @Sam We don't know the limit of $h_2(x)$ exists here... it's equivalent to the question being asked.

Comment: Aah I see. Thank you. Is there a function f such that $\lim_{x \to 0} f(2x)/2x = 0$, but $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)/x \ne 0$. Maybe it has something to do with the other condition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$ you can write $f(x)$ as a telescoping sum
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (f(2^{-n} x) - f(2^{-n-1}x))$$
$$ = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2^{-n - 1}x) {f(2^{-n} x) - f(2^{-n-1}x) \over 2^{-n - 1} x}$$
Thus one has
$$|f(x)| \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n - 1}|x| \bigg|{f(2^{-n} x) - f(2^{-n-1}x) \over 2^{-n - 1} x}\bigg|$$
$$\leq \bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{-n - 1}|x|\bigg)\sup_{n \geq 0} \bigg|{f(2^{-n} x) - f(2^{-n-1}x) \over 2^{-n - 1} x}\bigg|$$
$$= |x| \sup_{n \geq 0} \bigg|{f(2^{-n} x) - f(2^{-n-1}x) \over 2^{-n - 1} x}\bigg|$$
So we have
$$\bigg|{f(x) \over x}\bigg| \leq \sup_{n \geq 0} \bigg|{f(2^{-n} x) - f(2^{-n-1}x) \over 2^{-n - 1} x}\bigg|$$
Now the fact that ${\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to 0 }\frac{f(2x)- f(x)}{x} =0}$ shows that the supremum here goes to zero as $x \to 0$ and we are done.

Comment: +1. Nice proof!

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89619